# Error validating a regular expression with formBuilder

Tags: angular

I'm using `formBuilder` to validate my form. I have a field called `password` and I want to validate that it requires at least one `letter` and `one` number. for example `123456789a` must be accepted. I am using the following pattern:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

in fact in this link it can be seen that it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqr5abx3/1/

```
var password = '123456789a'; 
var validation=/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test(password); 
// returns true
alert(validation)
```

But in my application, no. My div appears showing the error

```
 this.register5 = formBuilder.group({password: [
     null,
     Validators.compose([
       Validators.required,
       Validators.minLength(7),
       Validators.maxLength(15),
       Validators.pattern('/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/')
     ])
   ]})

  <ion-item>
   <ion-label floating color="azul-2">Contraseña*</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="password" value="" [formControl]="createAccountService.register5.controls['password']"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <div class="error-box" *ngIf="createAccountService.register5.controls['password'].hasError('pattern') && createAccountService.register5.controls['password'].touched">No is the format correct</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz that reproduces the problem please?

Answer (score 2):

did u try removing "/" ?
like this

```
   Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$')
```